# Spotlight appears in the background of rendered image / video - how can I prevent it?

Tags: rendering, materials, lighting

I have a scene with a circular plane and three spotlights that shine down on it intermittently. Below is a screenshot of the scene (one of the lights is currently illuminating the plane):

[image: Screenshot of the scene]

In the final rendering, I only want the circular plane to be illuminated. However, when I render this scene, I instead see some light that appears off the plane. In the image below you can see that light in the lower-right corner of the image:

[image: Rendered scene]

My question is this: how can I stop the light from appearing in the background of the scene and appear only on the circular plane?

Source file here:
[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/help to upload your file.

Comment: Uploaded the file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9Y9K8M0e" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9Y9K8M0e/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden object (in viewport but visible in render mode). Unhide it with alt + h. I don't know if thats the issue.

Comment: That was it! I didn't realize that hidden objects can still render. Thanks for pointing out the obvious.